# invoke a websevice using PL/SQL - oracle 11g

Tags: xml, web-services, plsql, oracle11g, xml-parsing

i have to just passing an XML type data in a webservice and get two outputs. one is status and another one is response XML.

for a POC 
Now  it should just return the same input xml as response XML  and the  status as 'S'

i will use the webservice like like 'http://d3-a1-oa2-ipdv-05.xxx.com:9105/soa-infra/services/default/Webservice/bpelprocess1_client_ep?WSDL'

could you please help me in invoking a webservice using PLSQL oracle 11g.

Comment: I need to invoke a web service using PLSQL - oracle 11g.
 
i need to pass a XML data and get a response XML.
 
right now, for a  POC , i need to get the same inputs as response XML.

Comment: try to look around for utl_http https://community.oracle.com/thread/2460619 or for utl_soap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This https://tomkrueger.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/how-to-call-a-web-service-from-oracle-plsql be a good starting point if you opt for using the utl_dbws option.